# QML Map not giving any coordinates when component completes

Tags: qt, qml

i'm trying to get two coordinates from QML component `Map`. I tried to use standard `Component.onCompleted`. I am trying to get the coordinate that is at the **top left** and the coordinate that is at the **bottom right**.

I'm using `Map` function `toCoordinate` with `Qt.Point()` as a parameter.

Problem occurs when function is called, because output of this function is empty.

I am using Qt 5.12.3.

**Output:**

```
qml: 
qml:
```

**My code**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtLocation 5.9
import QtPositioning 5.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Map {
        id: map
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        height: parent.height + 20

        plugin: mapPlugin
        gesture.acceptedGestures: {
                    MapGestureArea.PanGesture      |
                    MapGestureArea.PinchGesture
        }

        Component.onCompleted: {
            console.log(map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(0,0)))
            console.log(map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(map.width, map.height)))
        }
    }

    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "osm"

        PluginParameter {
            name: "osm.mapping.cache.directory"
            value: "./cache/"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any solution for this problem? Did anyone have similiar problem?

Thank you for your help.

**//Edit:**

When I use `map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(0,0))` in `Map.onCenterChanged` and then move with `Map`, it returns valid coordinate.

Comment: Does `map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(0,0))` return a valid `coordinate`?

Comment: @SilvanoCerza Not in `Component.onCompleted`

Comment: What does `console.log(map.width, map.height)` return?

Comment: In `Component.onCompleted` it returns `qml: 0 20`, wich is wrong too.

Comment: It's because your `Window` size is still `0, 0`, the `Map` is 0, 20 because you add 20 to `parent.height`.

Comment: @SilvanoCerza But I set size of `Window` to `640x480`, how is that possible?

Comment: Little update, when I use `map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(0,0))` in `Map.onHeightChanged`, it works, but `Qt.Point(map.width, map,height)` still don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-map.html#mapReady-prop) points out:

> **mapReady : bool**
>
> This property holds whether the map has been successfully initialized
>   and is ready to be used. Some methods, such as fromCoordinate and
>   toCoordinate, will not work before the map is ready. **Due to the
>   architecture of the Map, it's advised to use the signal emitted for
>   this property in place of Component.onCompleted, to make sure that
>   everything behaves as expected.**

<sub>(The emphasis is mine)</sub>

Component.onCompleted does not guarantee that the map is rendered or has the information provided by the API, instead you must use the mapReady property:

```
Map {
    id: map
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right
    height: parent.height + 20

    plugin: mapPlugin
    gesture.acceptedGestures: {
        MapGestureArea.PanGesture |
        MapGestureArea.PinchGesture
    }

    onMapReadyChanged: {
        if(mapReady){
            console.log(map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(0,0)))
            console.log(map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(map.width, map.height)))
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
qml: 51° 32' 29.3" N, 1° 53' 7.8" W, 0m
qml: 51° 28' 23.1" N, 1° 37' 48.4" E, 0m
```